# Boost documents with all terms first in solr

Tags: solr, full-text-search, search-engine

I have a solr server that I use to index document with title and body fields
When I search by single word it works good but when I have a multi-terms query results are bad: some documents with only part of terms are ranked first (may be in relation to documents length)
How to boost documents with all terms first in results before docuemnts with only some terms ?
Is it possible to extend that with fuzzy search and date sorting?

Comment: show us your search query (and edismax or whatever handler)

Comment: What you want is the default behaviour - the more terms that match, the higher the score (.. depending on a few factors - if you have a very seldom used term in one document while all the other terms are used in almost every document, then the seldom used term will be ranked higher). Anything related at *sorting* will make scoring useless, but boosting by recency is maybe what you're thinking of?

Comment: @Persimmonium: this is the query I am using: response = solr.get 'select', :params => {
        :q=> q  ,
        :fl => "id,category,score",      
        :rows => 1000
     }     I am using  ruby but the query is the basic one